# Show that $|BD| = 2y \tan 2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

In the triangle $ABC$, the angle at $C$ is $90^o$, $|AC|=y$.

$D$ is a point on $[BC]$.

Angle $BAD=2\theta$, and angle $DAC=45^o -\theta$.

$0^o \lt \theta \lt 45^o$

Show that $|BD|=2y\tan 2\theta$

I've been looking at this for a few days and can't figure it out.

It is a question in a section on double-angle formulae so I started with:

$\tan(2\theta+(45^o -\theta))=\frac{|BD|+|DC|}{y}=\frac{\tan 2\theta +\frac{|DC|}{y}}{1-(\tan 2\theta)(\frac{|DC|}{y})}$

Then I tried starting with:

$\tan (\theta +45^o)=\frac{\tan \theta +1}{1-\tan \theta}$

I tried tidying up the expressions but to no avail.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By rule of sine we have

$$\frac{|BD|}{\sin 2\theta}=\frac{|DA|}{\sin (45°-\theta)}$$

and $|DA|$ can be related to $|AC|=y$.

[image]

Comment: The angle opposite $|DA|$ is $45^o -3\theta$, not $45^o -2\theta$. Also, I tried that approach but didn't get anywhere. Did you manage to solve it using that approach?

Comment: @Derek Sorry maybe I didn't get the givens. I've added a sketch, it seems to me that angle in $B$ is $45°-2\theta$.

Comment: @Derek I misunderstood the condition for the angle in A, now it shoud be fixed.

Comment: @Derek Note that the angle opposite to $|DA|$ is $45^o -\theta$ maybe you confusion raised from here!

Comment: You are right, the angle opposite $DA$ is $45^o - \theta$. But I still can't solve the problem. I got an expression for $\sin 2\theta$ and another for $\cos 2\theta$ and then used them to get an expression for $\tan 2\theta$. But it doesn't simplify to the desired result.

Comment: @Derek What is $|DA|$ in terms of $45^o - \theta$?

Comment: $|DA|=\frac{|BD|\sin (45^o -\theta)}{\sin 2\theta}$

Comment: More simply, we have that $|DA|=y/\cos(45^o - \theta)$.

Comment: How is that useful? I can't see where that approach is going.

Comment: You can solve easily in that way, starting from the given identity and recall that $$\sin(45-\theta)\cos(45-\theta)=\frac12 \cos 2\theta$$

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: Well done! You are welcome, Bye